# Failed to upgrade the iOS application while app is doing network operations using sockets

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

When I am trying to update the application using `iTunes`, I am getting a error pop-up - Unable to download application.
I am running into this error **`only`** when my app is doing network operations using sockets.
In other scenarios where app is either not running or is idle, it works correctly.

From the `console logs`, I got following `error message` -

```
2013-04-18 10:11:39 AM GMT+07:00 backboardd <Warning>: pid_suspend failed for [7104]: Unknown error: -1, Unknown error: -1
2013-04-18 10:11:39 AM GMT+07:00 backboardd <Warning>: Could not set priority of [7104] to 4096, priority: No such process
2013-04-18 10:11:39 AM GMT+07:00 backboardd <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.avaya.AVSIPiPhoneCFE[0xe6ed]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
```

Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: Is your app requesting any background execution privileges (Music, VOIP, etc.)?

Comment: Yes. It is VOIP application. and have set these privileges.

Answer (score 0):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332422/ios-app-will-not-die-writes-to-console-plays-sounds-after-quit) addresses a similar problem.

In short, iOS automatically restarts an app that crashes or exits abnormally, if it has a background execution flag set. It seems that this leads to iTunes being unable to overwrite the old binary with the new one, because it's still running.

Comment: Hmmm. But while upgrading the app, iOS is going to terminate any running application so it doesn't make sense for iOS to restart it while upgrading. does it? Another point to be noted is, if the application is in connected state with server then this issue does not occur. This is reproducible only when application is in process of connecting with server. I mean to say it is process of establishing socket connections, doing handshakes etc.

Comment: I meant to say that perhaps iTunes trying to shut down your app triggers a crash, which in turn triggers an unexpected restart. Can you confirm that your app doesn't crash on applicationWillTerminate: received during the process of connecting to the server?